# Change metadata on several images at once

Tags: software-recommendation, photos, metadata

How can I change the metadata for several images at the same time (batch edit)? For example, comments and titles.

Comment: You have not made it clear, are you referring to Pantheon Photos, or are you looking for another application to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two good tools to edit meta-data of image-files:

exiftool and exiv2

**exiftool:**

You will find exif [here: official site](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

It also has a graphical frontend: [frontend for exif](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/fotopreprocessor/)

**exiv2:**

This is a better tool than **exiftool**. You can find it here: [official site](http://www.exiv2.org/).
Here is a man page on how to use this: [exiv2 man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/exiv2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing gThumb Image Viewer, by typing on the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gthumb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gthumb
```